# How do I achieve a vintage photo effect in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color, reverse-engineering

How can I achieve this vintage color tone in Photoshop?

[image: ]]]

Comment: Seems similar in technique to http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12264/269

Comment: tutorial: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-give-your-photos-a-vintage-polaroid-effect

Comment: Try using camera raw filter split toning. Shadows are blue, lights are some orange/yellow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Curves adjustment layer gives you ultimate flexibility.

Edit each channel individually:

- Red: raise the bottom left point.
- Green: make a new point in the center and drop it slightly.
- Blue: raise the bottom left point and lower the top right point, then make a new point at the center and drop it slightly.

Experiment with the opacity of the adjustment layer to vary the intensity of the effect.

Comment: +1 I tried it and it yielded a very dramatic result. Nice answer.

Comment: It's a good technique definitely. If you set the Blend mode to Overlay, you get a nice boost in contrast as well; you see the effect in a lot of wedding photography these days. Try it on a black and white image as well, some interesting toning effects.

Comment: yeah that's what I did and i could not believe the contrast. I used B&W. This must produce the "bronze" skin tone look when used on a color photo.

Answer (score 3):

Use the brightness/contrast tool to reduce contrast, then use the colour balance tool and drag the highlights toward yellow and red, and the shadows toward cyan and blue.

Comment: yes, you are close, but there is one or two steps that still seem missing.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend using a gradient map adjustment layer, you could even import that image and sample the colors to get you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: infact it appears that the left gradient color should be R:42 G:51 B:93   and right R:232 G:210 B:187

Comment: If you use a gradient adjustment layer, what blending mode do you use?  Color, or something like Soft Light?

Answer (score 2):

Download a texture, wall or something rugged and copy the texture over your photo in photoshop as a new layer and set the blending mode of the texture to overlay or softlight.
you can get here many free textures http://www.paper-backgrounds.com

Answer (score 1):

You might as well want to look for an effect called "cross processing". Although I am aware it is not totally the effect of your example picture, but the principle is the same.

One example:
http://layersmagazine.com/curvy-cross-processing.html