# How does Akif Hakan Celebi manipulate his images?

Tags: image-manipulation

[Akif Hakan Çelebi](http://hakanphotography.deviantart.com/) is a great photographer, and his works are obviously manipulated via Photoshop, how does he manipulate? Which progress will give those results?

Because of spam mechanism and new user aproach I can only share one **NSFW** [Example](http://th06.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2012/267/0/1/01d8239323d1d6e53fb0f1623e95ea54-d5fsf2l.jpg) :(

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: As he's on deviantart he might also use it as tool to communicate with his fans. Have you tried asking him?

Comment: Well thats a good question, but I think he wont answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the adjustment given in the accepted answer to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12836/how-do-i-achieve-a-vintage-photo-effect-in-photoshop) but experiment with the green point to give a slightly green cast. Also lower the contrast a little using curves or levels.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it but how about this one: http://hakanphotography.deviantart.com/art/The-Animal-Instinct-3-282506564

Comment: Same idea but with more of a red/purple tint