# Old photography effect in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I don't know anything about photography so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question. Can I recreate something like this

[image]

[image]

in Photoshop with a photo I took with smartphone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I edit a photo to have a old vintage look?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39546/how-to-i-edit-a-photo-to-have-a-old-vintage-look)

Comment: Also [How do I achieve a vintage photo effect in Photoshop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12836/how-do-i-achieve-a-vintage-photo-effect-in-photoshop)

Comment: Also this one [How was the twilight blue color effect in this photo produced?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/how-was-the-twilight-blue-color-effect-in-this-photo-produced/)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get film looks in Photoshop is to use the Analog Efex free plugin: https://www.google.com/nikcollection/products/analog-efex-pro/
With some experimentation with different film types you should be able to get something close with minimal effort.

Alternatively, you can try matching the color and tone using levels and curves with this technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHvfVc_8eMc
You may be able to get a closer look, but it will take more fiddling.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional color print has three color layers - cyan, magenta and yellow. The "old" look is caused by the fact that cyan dyes in the photographic paper deteriorate first and yellow are the most stable.

So in order to recreate this look from scratch, you would want to lighten cyans and little bit of the magentas.

If you want the pictures to really look like old faded prints, you would also need to recreate the film look (something that your examples do not have - they look digital). I would personally look for a plugin that can do that. In Photoshop, as a starting point, you can tweak the tone curve to an S-shape.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these photos are desaturated and have lower contrast with a warmer look, you can download filters depending on the platform which you are editing. Look for a 'film look' or 'vintage' filter.